# Why do these seemingly equivalent function definitions yield different results?

Tags: scala, function, expression

TYPE A:

```
val even1 = (x:Int)  => { println("in even1"); x % 2 == 0}
```

Output on REPL:

```
even1: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

TYPE B:

```
val even2 : Int => Boolean  = { println("in even2");_% 2 == 0}
```

Output on REPL :

```
in even2
even2: Int => Boolean = <function1>
```

I know the difference between 'def' and 'val' declaration of a function, above condition is looking a bit different to me. Please help me understand the distinction...

Answer (score 5):

`even1` and `even2` are indeed not equivalent. To understand why, here is a different but equivalent way of defining `even2`:

```
val even2 : Int => Boolean = { println("in even2"); x => x % 2 == 0 }
```

Now... The right-hand side (RHS) of `even1`'s definition is a function that takes an `Int` and returns a block that contains a print statement, followed by a boolean expression.

In contrast, in `even2`'s case, the function and the block are "inside out": the right-hand side is a block that contains a print statement and a function of type `Int => Boolean`.

In Scala, a *block* is an expression, and the result of that expression is the result of the last expression (if any; `()` otherwise) that the block contains. Therefore, the `println` statement in `even1` is executed every time `even1` is called, whereas the `println` statement in `even2` is executed only once, when `even2` is defined.

Comment: `The println statement in even1 is executed every time even1 is called, whereas the println statement in even2 is executed only once, when even2 is defined`. Why? The answer you provide (as is) would apply also for `even1`: `The right-hand side is a block...`

Comment: I want to ask same, why this different behaviour?as both function, declaration looks same on REPL output

Comment: @jarandaf No. The right-hand side of `even1`'s definition is, not a block, but a function: `(x:Int)  => { println("in even1"); x % 2 == 0}`.